# Accessing an entry in an array within Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This seems like it should be simple but I can't get it to work. I simply want to draw a circle and the x coordinate of the center to be specified by an entry in a given array. For example suppose I want to draw circles centered at `(1,1)`, `(1,2)`

```
\def\testarray{1,2}
\def\circleHeights{1,2}

\foreach \y in circleHeights {

\filldraw [black] (\testarray[1],\y) circle (1pt);
```

Doesn't work. But it does work replacing `\testarray[1]` with just `1`. How to you properly access an array? I've done a bit of searching and I've tried using `\pgfmathparse` and `\pgfmathsetmacro`:
For example as

```
\foreach \y in circleHeights {
\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\testarray[1]}
\filldraw [black] (\x,\y) circle (1pt);
```

I've also tried the array defined like `\def\testarray{{1,2}}` since I saw some examples like that as well. I realize that I could do the above task easily without needing to access the array, but in my actual situation I need to do something like this. So I'd like to find a way to make this approach work

Comment: After `\def\testarray{1,2}`, if you feed `\testarray[1]` you simply obtain `1,2[1]`. TeX just expands the macro; it has no concept of arrays (unless you teach it to).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you define a macro to store an array (for use with `pgfmath`) you have to use surrounding braces:

```
\def\testarray{{1,2}}
```

Note that indexing starts with zero.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\def\testarray{{1,2}}
\def\circleHeights{{0.5,2}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines,step=.5](0,0)grid(3,3);
\foreach \i in {0,1}
  \filldraw[black] (\testarray[\i],\circleHeights[\i]) circle[radius=1pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just to extend @esdd's answer you can use a 2-dimensional array instead:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\def\testarray{{{1,0.5},{2,2}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines,step=.5](0,0)grid(3,3);
\foreach \i in {0,1}
  \filldraw[black] (\testarray[\i][0],\testarray[\i][1]) circle[radius=1pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, there is only one array containing the coordinates as pairs.