# How can I use arrays in a PGF axis environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, programming, axis

I would like to use an array in a PGF axis environment. This array would have the parameters values of a function to be plotted. I tried writing the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\def\a{{1,2}}  %Array definition

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]

\addplot [
    domain=0:10,
    samples=100, 
    color=blue,
]
{(\a[0])+(\a[1])*x}; %Function to plot

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I got an error in Texmaker, that says the following:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit
got an ill-formatted floating point number `0.0'. The unreadable part was near
'0.0'. (in '({1,2}[0])+({1,2}[1])*x').
```

It seems that the function environment doesn't allow the use of arrays. There are some tikz commands that accept it, as is the case of \filldraw (you may see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227509/accessing-an-entry-in-an-array-within-tikz)). Is there any way to do this still using arrays and the axis environment?

Comment: Sorry! I had a range which I tried to change here for the sake of simplicity. I ended forgetting the comma in the process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `pgfplots` switches on `fpu` and uses it, hence the error message. (You'd need `{...}` but this does not solve the problem here.) One way to make it work is to store the array entries in macros, which you use.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\def\myarray{{1,2}}  %Array definition
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mya}{\myarray[0]}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myb}{\myarray[1]}
\addplot [domain=0:10,color=blue] {\mya+\myb*x}; %Function to plot
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It now works! Thank you!